# Installing Spark on ubuntu

Tags: java, openjdk, jdk, oracle, jre

I am installing Spark IM Client for Ubuntu.

The tar.gz doesn't appear to be functional at ALL, (considering the `/bin` directory is completely empty and lacks important things like `unpack200`) but I have a `.deb` for 2.6.0.  It's not the latest version, but it'll do.

The issue is, I can't satisfy its dependency for `sun-java6-jre`.  I'm fairly certain using OpenJDK will work, I just need the deb to go through.

How can I fix this?  Can I install a dummy `sun-java6-jre` package somehow, then use OpenJDK?  Or is there a way to ACTUALLY install `sun-java6-jre` even after all this craziness of Ubuntu removing Sun/Oracle Java from their repositories?

Answer (score 1):

The java wiki page does tell you how to install sun-java6-jre manually if you choose to do so. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java

32-bit

```
$ wget http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u31-b04/jre-6u31-linux-i586.bin
$ chmod u+x jre-6u31-linux-i586.bin
$ ./jre-6u31-linux-i586.bin
$ sudo mv jre1.6.0_31 /usr/lib/jvm/
$ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.6.0_31/bin/java" 1
$ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so" "mozilla-javaplugin.so" "/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.6.0_31/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so" 1
```

Then

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
$ sudo update-alternatives --config mozilla-javaplugin.so
```

Answer (score 1):

I installed Spark 2.6.3 on my Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit system. I installed Oracle Java 1.7 using the instructions for Java installation (Step 2) found [here](http://ubuntuserverguide.com/2013/01/how-to-setup-chat-server-using-openfire-in-ubuntu-server-12-04.html).

To get Spark to run, because it comes with a 32 bit JRE, I had to modify the `./Spark` script to get it to find the Oracle JRE, and also so it would accept version 1.7.

Changes to line 4 (was commented out, added location of oracle JRE):

> INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle

Changes to line 95 (change "6" to "7"):

> if [ "$ver_minor" -gt "7" ]; then

These changes should be made properly in the Spark installation script so Spark supports the newer computers.